# iBeacon Ranging Service Not Returning any Beacons

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am working with the iBeacon technology, and I am trying to create a RangingService that will search for nearby iBeacons every five seconds and run in the background of my application. The code below is not working. I'm sure I'm making some dumb mistake somewhere, but I can see in my log files that Checkpoint 3 and 4 are being reached every five seconds, while Checkpoints 1 and 2 are never being reached. Thus, the nearby beacons are not being detected. I don't have much experience with Services or Beacons, so I would appreciate any help, especially from @davidgyoung.

Please forgive me if the code below isn't indented perfectly :) Thanks so much to anyone who can help me.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

import java.util.Collection;

public class RangingService extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {
private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
Handler handler;
String b = "";

@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
    Log.d("Service", "Started");

    handler = new Handler(){

        @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                Log.d("Checkpoint", "5 seconds have passed");
            }

        };

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(true)
                {
                    try {
                        startJob();
                        Log.d("Checkpoint", "Job has started");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }).start();




        //return START_STICKY;
    }

public void startJob() {
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    Log.d("The first beacon", "Starting job for realzies");
    onBeaconServiceConnect();
}


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("Service", "Ended");
    }

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Log.d("Checkpoint3", "Checkpoint3");
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

           Log.d("Checkpoint1", "Checkpoint1");
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Log.d("Checkpoint2", "Checkpoint2");
                //EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
                Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                String a = "The first beacon " + firstBeacon.toString() + " is about " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away. RSSI = " + firstBeacon.getRssi();
                Log.d("Service", a);
                //logToDisplay(a);
            }
        }

    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        Log.d("Checkpoint4", "Checkpoint4");

    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
 }
}// Update code formatting
```

Main Activity:

```
public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever   a Beacon
    // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
    Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
    startService(new Intent(this, RangingService.class));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

1. Don't call `onBeaconServiceConnect();` manually.  This is a callback method that gets called by the Android Beacon Library when the beacon scanning service is ready to go as a result of the call to `beaconManager.bind(this);`  If you call it yourself, you defeat its purpose, and will cause problems.
2. You should not call `beaconManager.bind(this);` every five seconds -- just call it once when the service starts up.  Calling it repeatedly will cause problems.
3. Make sure that the Android Beacon Library is configured for the types of beacons you are using.  By default it will only detect open source AltBeacon packets.  If you are using a proprietary beacon type, you need to create a `BeaconParser` and add configure it with the library.  You can do a Google search for "BeaconParser" and your proprietary beacon type to get the proper line of code to configure the library.

Comment: Thank you so much. I made all three of those changes, and my code has now reached checkpoint 1 and 2. However, it is only detecting the beacon once. I want it to keep receiving the location of the beacon (distance) every five seconds. How can I implement this? Thanks again - I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please create a new question and link to it from here?  The problem you are having has changed significantly, and so has the code based on the changes you describe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35702632/ibeacon-ranging-service-not-returning-any-beacons-part-2    Thank you!