# iBeacon Ranging Service Not Returning any Beacons (Part 2)

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

My code has now reached checkpoint 1 and 2. However, it is only detecting the beacon once. I want it to keep receiving the location of the beacon (distance) every five seconds. How can I implement this? Thanks again

```
public class RangingService extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {
private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
Handler handler;
String b = "";



@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        Log.d("Service", "Started");
        beaconManager.bind(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));


        handler = new Handler(){

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                Log.d("Checkpoint", "5 seconds have passed");
            }

        };

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(true)
                {
                    try {
                        startJob();
                        Log.d("Checkpoint", "Job has started");
                        Thread.sleep(5285);
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }).start();




        //return START_STICKY;
    }

public void startJob() {
    Log.d("Checkpoint", "Starting job for realzies");

    //onBeaconServiceConnect();
}


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("Service", "Ended");
        beaconManager.unbind(this);

    }

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Log.d("Checkpoint3", "Checkpoint3");
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {

           Log.d("Checkpoint1", "Checkpoint1");
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Log.d("Checkpoint2", "Checkpoint2");
                //EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
                Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                String a = "The first beacon " + firstBeacon.toString() + " is about " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away. RSSI = " + firstBeacon.getRssi();
                Log.d("Service", a);
                //logToDisplay(a);
            }
        }

    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        Log.d("Checkpoint4", "Checkpoint4");

    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not obvious to me why it is only scanning detecting beacons once.  You might try adding debug lines to log any exceptions in all the empty catch blocks.  You might also try stopping ranging before you unbind from the BeaconManager (although this should not be strictly necessary.)  It is also worth noting that this may not be the easiest way to do this -- the library already starts its own service and can be configured to send ranging results approx. every 5 seconds simply by setting `beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(4000l); beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1100l);`

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. How would I use the setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod function? Would I call it from the Main Activity and just get rid of the service that I created? (Sorry if these are basic questions - I'm an amateur programmer) thanks again :)

Comment: See my comment under @Chris_Wilson's answer.  He is on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you remove the Handler and the Thread as they seem unnecessary here.

I think all you need do is remove the Handler and the Thread, and run beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod as follows.  Additionally, as best active you should probably bind the BeaconManager after setting all of its properties.

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5285);
beaconManager.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I really appreciate the help. Would I include this piece of code in my main Activity or in the service class?

Comment: It all depends on what you're trying to do, but unless you have a specific reason to use a service you may not want to.  You could bind the BeaconManager in your activity onCreate or onResume if you'd like.

Comment: I agree this is a better approach.  If you only need to access beacon scan results from a single activity, just put this code in that activity's onCreate method.  If you need to share results between multiple activities, you can do the ranging from a custom Android Application class, and similarly put the code in its onCreate method.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much @ChrisWilson and @davidgyoung! I got it to work with your help :)  I'm so grateful...thanks so much!!

Comment: Good point @davidgyoung.  In an application I'm working on we use a custom Application class because we want to maintain our ranging at all times.  It just depends on when you want to be ranging.